# Code Igniter subquery with Active record

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, subquery

I'm trying to do this query in Code Igniter:

```
Select 
    items_mtoedifsing.Marca,
    items_mtoedifsing.Modelo,
    items_mtoedifsing.Familia,
    items_movimientos.id_item,
    items_movimientos.Tipo_Movimiento,
    items_movimientos.Fecha_Movimiento,
    items_movimientos.Destino   
from items_movimientos
JOIN items_mtoedifsing ON items_mtoedifsing.id_item=items_movimientos.id_item
where 
        items_movimientos.fecha_movimiento = (Select max(fecha_movimiento) from items_movimientos it where it.id_item=items_movimientos.id_item) 
        and items_movimientos.Destino='value'
```

But I'm having some issues with the subquery. This is my code that return 0 rows when itshould return 1 row:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('items_movimientos');
$this->db->join('items_mtoedifsing', 'items_mtoedifsing.id_item = items_movimientos.id_item');
$this->db->where('items_movimientos.Fecha_Movimiento', '(Select max(fecha_movimiento) from items_movimientos it where it.id_item=items_movimientos.id_item)');
$this->db->where('items_movimientos.Destino', $param);
```

What can I do with this part:

```
$this->db->where('items_movimientos.Fecha_Movimiento', '(Select max(fecha_movimiento) from items_movimientos it where it.id_item=items_movimientos.id_item)');
```

Comment: Honestly, for the more intense queries like that, I usually use query binding instead of the active record way. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Comment: yeah, i have used this method always but now im learning to use active record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using active record you can do so,by passing second parameter as null and third parameter as FALSE.

```
$subquery="(Select max(fecha_movimiento) 
           from items_movimientos it 
           where it.id_item=items_movimientos.id_item)";
$this->db->where('items_movimientos.Fecha_Movimiento ='.$subquery, null,FALSE);
```

Comment: Could you explain whats the second and third parameter is for?

Comment: From doc: 
$this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

Comment: @RahilWazir passing second parameter as null tells active record there is nothing to compare with and the third parameter as null will prevent the query to be quoted by active record so the subquery expression will execute as it is we pass to otherwise if third is not set to false then the subquery exprssion will be quoted by active record which will produce error